# Which version of magit am I installing?

Tags: package, magit

Here is a snapshot of my list-package result related to `magit`:

[image: magit]

Question:

1. There's nothing in my `init.el` on marmalade, why the package from marmalade are also listed?
2. If I run <kbd>M-x</kbd>`package-install`<kbd>RET</kbd>`magit`<kbd>RET</kbd>, which version am I installing?

Comment: Do `M-x rgrep RET marmalade RET * RET ~/.emacs.d/`. Something will turn up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why marmalade packages might be appearing in the list (assuming you are correct that your `init.el` does not have anything related to marmalade). As for which package gets installed, `package` will by default install the package with highest version number. In this case the `magit` package on `melpa-stable` (90141214) will be installed since it has the highest version.

Do understand about version comparison read the documentation of the function `version=` (<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`version=`<kbd>RET</kbd>) which explains the algorithm used to compare versions.

Comment: Your explanation is quite clear. Thanks. May I ask why the melpa-stable version starts with 90, is there special meaning?

Answer (score 5):

> May I ask why the melpa-stable version starts with 90, is there special meaning?

`9014****` is bigger than `2014****`. I have chosen that as a temporary solution so that users of Melpa-Stable get the stable version without having to pin Magit to Melpa-Stable. Temporary because eventually the version will go "down" to `2.1.0`. The `9014****` tags are specifically for Melpa-Stable, without that the Melpa-Stable version would be `1.2.2` and that release isn't really "stable" - it is very old (only some bug fixes since `1.2.0`) and contains *many* known issues which have been fixed on Magit's `master` branch a long time ago.

By the way `9014****` and `2014****` are usually build from the same commit at the tip of `master`. Sometimes I don't create a `9014****` tag after applying some insignificant change like a doc-string fix, then Melpa-Stable lags behind a bit.

No new development happens on `master` now - so it is "stable". The next release will be based on the `next` branch and that branch has also already been feature frozen, see [Roadmap toward 2.1.0](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1645).

---

> `0.8.1`

The presence of `0.8.1` in that list indicates that there is something wrong with your `package.el` installation. No Elpa repository contains that version anymore. Things to check are whether you have an ancient version of `package.el` laying around on your `load-path` and whether there are old files in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation on magit versions. I'm using `Emacs 24.4`, built from scratch. There'a a ~/.emacs.d.bak folder which contains old files. I guess Emacs won't read this folder. I should delete this foler and using `git` to manage these files. By the way, which package management tool do you use, the built-in `package-install`, or `el-get`?

Comment: Neither, I am using git submodules. I had some tools to do it but they have bit rotten and so I do it mostly by hand, which isn't as bad as all the submodule haters think. For compiling I use my `packed` and `auto-compile` packages. Eventually I will resurrect my other related tools and publish them. Actually I am currently preparing for that.